# Why does Extrude and Inset not use the same measuring units?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude, units, measurement

Hello there Community,

I'm modeling a simple blocky logo and want to inset and then extrude by exactly the same amount, but this doesn't happen.

When I inset a face by 0.00115...

[image: First Step: Inset]

and extrude then by -0.00115, this happens:

[image: Second Step: Extrude]

What I want is something like this:

[image: Estimate of what it should look like]

Am I missing something here? Is it a bug? Is it a feature?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello :). Notice that you missed a *1* when extruding... you only entered **0.0015**

Comment: Hey there, that's very true, but that means that the extrusion should be even greater, but it's still not even close to the insertion.

Comment: Okay :). It matches perfectly on my end, perhaps your object doesn't have uniform scale? *Object > Apply > Scale*

Comment: THANK YOU! That fixed it, although I got a workaround already! Thank you for this though, now inserting is the same as extruding!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jachym Michal pointed out my object didn't have uniform scale.

Object > Apply > Scale fixed it for me!